# Open Sets Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $A,B ⊆ ℝ$.

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are open, then (i) $A \cup B$ is open, and (ii) $A \cap B$ is open.

Workings:

Proof: (i)

Let $x \in A \cup B$

Must find a neighbourhood $y$ of $x$ such that $y \subseteq A \cup B$

Since $x \in A \cup B$, $x \in A$ or $x \in B$

If $x \in A$, then there is a neighbourhood $y$ of $x$ such that $y \subseteq A$

And since $A \subseteq A \cup B$, $y \subset A \cup B$

If $x \subseteq B$, then there is a neighbourhood $y$ of $x$ such that $y \subseteq B$

Since $B \subseteq A \cup B$, $y \subseteq A \cup B$

So $A \cup B$ is open.

I'm wondering if this is correct and I'm not too sure how to do (ii).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: HINT: For (ii), if $x \in (A \cap B)$, then $x \in A$ AND $x \in B$.

Comment: Let $x \subseteq A \cap B$. Must find a neighbourgood $y$ of $x$ such that $y \subseteq A \cap B$.

Since $x \in A \cap B$, $x \in A$ and $x \in B$,

Since $x \in A$, there is a neighbourhhood $y$ of $x$ such that $y \subseteq A$.

And since $A \subseteq A \cap B, y \subseteq A \cap B$

Since $x \in B$, there is a neighbourhood $y$ in $x$ such that $y \subseteq B$.

And since $B \subseteq A \cap B$, $y \subseteq A \cap B$.

So $A \cap B$ is open.

Comment: Would it not be easier to say that the definition of a topological space is that there are the open sets such that any finite intersections and arbitrary unions of opes sets are open.

Comment: @MrTambourineMan looks good except that you only need to find one neighbourhood i.e. just use the fact that $x \in A$, that will do the job. Also go ahead and answer your own question so as to close this discussion.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.